# benefits of allocating huge pages at boot

Tags: linux, memory, huge-pages

[ moving the question from StackOverflow where it seems less appropriate ]

The kernel boots with `default_hugepagesz=1G` option, which defines size of the default page size. So when an application want large memory, the kernel will allocate it with 1G pages.

If the kernel boots with `hugepages=N`, i.e. allocate N huge pages at boot. So in this case, the kernel will automatically take a page from this pool, thus saving time on allocating memory?

When this pool runs out of available pages, how will the kernel allocate huge memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of allocating huge pages at boot is that the pages are pre-allocated, before memory is fragmented. The amount of allocated huge pages can also be changed at runtime, and an overcommit limit can be set — the kernel will allocate new huge pages if necessary, up to the overcommit limit, as long as enough pages are available to convert to huge pages.

See [the relevant kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/mm/hugetlbpage.html) for details.